# Tomcat when doing ssl termination session isn't detected

Tags: tomcat

Could anything be different when using `nginx` (nginx controller in Kubernetes cluster) to do SSL termination and sending data to apache and tomcat as plain HTTP which could prevent our app from detecting the login session?

Everything works fine expect that our app has something called `DetectLogin` class and it doesn't detect the user session when using `nginx` SSL termination. If I disable `nginx` SSL termination and enable SSL passthrough then our app can detect the Login session.

In the logs I see that `Port 8009` AJP port is handling the detect login but it isn't detecting the session.

Our traffic flow is like LB -> Nginx controller -> Apache httpd (for static content) -> Tomcat (for serving JSP content). Apache forwards all JSP related to tomcat using AJP port using `(mod_jk)`.

Any suggestions on troubleshooting this will help.

Comment: Your authentication might use cookies with the secure bit. Maybe Apache drops those cookies, when accessed through HTTP. Can you provide some configuration excerpts of the 3 servers (the proxy configuration of NGINX and Apache, the `server.xml` from Tomcat)? Why don't you proxy the requests for JSPs directly from NGINX to Tomcat?

Comment: Yea I'll proxy the nginx to tomcat after few days. Need to get it working just like old setup for now using apache and tomcat. Where can I configure the cookies secure bit?

Comment: Add some configuration to your question. My guess is: Tomcat decides whether the connection is secure or not based on the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header and Apache2 sets this header according to the way NGINX connects with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Piotr P. Karwasz Thanks for your comment I was able to figure out that nginx session cookie name was same as TOMCAT cookie name. I disabled all of the following since I was just testing if it had any effect. Disabling or changing the `session-cookie-name` resolved the issue.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "JSESSIONID"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity-mode: "persistent"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"
```